# how to create map package programatically using C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, add-in, toolbar, map-package

I'm using .NET SDK to create ArcMap toolbar with arcgis 10.1. how do i create map package .mpk programatically?

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006600000403000000

Comment: I want to call Share As-> Map Package Menu programatically. However command specified here (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000029s000000) does not work.